# What can I do to avoid such behavior?

Tags: discussion

Ok so from this morning, I've rejected 10+ suggested edits from this user: https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/38476/nits

What he was doing was adding the [magento-1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.9) tag to every Magento 1 questions. Most of the time there was no clue the OP was running 1.9 so I rejected almost every edit he made saying it could cause harm.

However, it seems like most of the edit I rejected still got approved -_-:

- https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62077
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62130
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62133
- https://magento.stackexchange.com/review/suggested-edits/62144

I don't feel like going through every single post he edited and remove the tag, what can I do ?

Comment: all I can see 2 against 1 in voting..

Comment: Someone call the romanian army!

Comment: There are other moderators you know.

Comment: @Marius yeah I know sorry if you felt spammed by me, didn't want to be annoying I just felt overwhelmed by all those edits that I coudln't handle

Comment: Calling @Nits can you please refrain from adding 1.9 tags to questions which aren't obvious they're running 1.9?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I have also seen these kinds of edits and rejected them checking the "causes harm" option and adding a comment like "The OP doesn't state anywhere that this question is about [magento-1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.9)"

I do agree with Fabian that you can do a "reject and edit", but sometimes the question text doesn't even clearly indicate that it is about Magento 1 **only**, so changing the [magento-1.9](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1.9) tag into [magento-1](https://magento.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/magento-1) doesn't seems right to me.

I agree with Qaisar that we should make a clear difference between Magento 1 and 2, but only when this is applicable. If the OP doesn't mention it, (and you care about it) you should ask him/her by **placing a comment**, not just blindly accept the 1.9 tag edit...

For now, in my opinion, we should just keep on rejecting these edits. By the way, I did go through a user's edit history once to correct all of his edits of this kind ;)

Answer (score 1):

now days it is necessary to separate question either it belong to `magento-1` OR `magento-2`. as you said it is annoying to see this kind of edit but these are necessary so i `approve` these kind of `edit`. That all in my defense.

Comment: Suggestion: **reject and edit** instead and apply the `magento-1` tag instead of `magento-1.9`

Comment: @fschmengler i think we already discuss  here: http://meta.magento.stackexchange.com/questions/778/usage-of-the-magento-1-tag-if-no-version-is-specified-in-question/

Comment: Fabian's point was discussed, Qaisar, not the point in your answer. `magento-1.9` tag is specific to 1.9. `magento-1 tag` is for questions where version of M1 is uncertain or for taxonomy. BTW I edited your comment to make the link work 

Answer (score 1):

Same for https://magento.stackexchange.com/users/18639/umesh-kumar who has done lot of edits last days ... just putting original texts into quotes.

This does not improve anything ...

I accept a lot of minor edits, but this is wasted time.

Rolled back some of this edits, but it has no affect for repution points ... Can someone contact him to stop this?